# Detect browser proxy setting only if proxy server is available else go via default network

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, proxy, internet-explorer

I am trying to browse via any browser which are installed on your OS.

Settings should be like this.

1. If there is proxy server in your network then browser should use proxy server to browse
2. If there is no proxy settings detected then it should go via default internet connection.

To be more clear about my question, I am mentioning the scenario which I am facing.

We have users who usage system in office as well as in home. In office proxy server is available, using which they browse. If they go home and if they do not use VPN and when they connect to internet user should not need to change proxy settings or disable the browser setting in browser. It should be detected automatically.

Let me know if you require any further information in this regard. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution to this is to set up WPAD.  This is a protocol many browsers support for learning how to use a proxy on a network automatically.  This is done by hosting a PAC file on you network, and using DNS and/or DHCP to inform the clients of its existence.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config